# Can't find the text file?

Tags: c++, codelite

Hi guys i run this code and everything is good but when i go to the containing folder i can't find the text file !!..

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


int main(){
    std::ofstream out_file{"../mohamed.txt"};
    std::string line {};
    if(!out_file){
        std::cerr<<"problem creating file"<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout<<"Enter a text to the out file : ";
    std::getline(std::cin,line);
    out_file<<line<<std::endl;

    out_file.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It works for me. How are you launching the program ? If you are using an IDE, it may run it in another folder.

Comment: Please add to the question your OS and IDE/compiler used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to notice about file paths is that they are relative to *current working directory*, **not** (necessarily) the path at which you find the executable!

Let's say, for instance, your executable resides in `/someLocalPath/myProject/bin` and you do on command line:

```
cd /someLocalPath/myProject
bin/myExe some parameters
```

Then, as current working directory is `myProject`, you'll find the output file in `someLocalPath`, not `myProject`

To get a hint at where to look, you could print the current working directory to console, have a look at [`std::filesystem::current_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) for how to get.